# Was there a specific place outside the camp were the red heifer was slaughtered in Numbers 19:1-3?

Tags: law, numbers, moses, sacrifice

Numbers 19:1-3 NASB

19 Then the Lord spoke to Moses and Aaron, saying, 2 “This is the statute of the law which the Lord has commanded, saying, ‘Speak to the sons of Israel that they bring you an unblemished red heifer in which there is no defect and on which a yoke has never [a]been mounted. 3 And you shall give it to Eleazar the priest, and it shall be brought outside the camp and be slaughtered in his presence.

There were a lot of specifics concerning sin offerings and burnt sacrifices
like it should be male,one year old, brought to the doorway of the Tabernacle,blood splashed on the side of the altar.There is no mention of a specific place were the heifer should be slaughtered

Was there a specific place outside the camp?

Answer (score 1):

Was there a specific place outside the camp?

Note that at the time, the Israelites were wandering in the wilderness. There was not even a fixed place for the camp. The place outside the camp for this sacrifice had to be with respect to the mobile camp itself as suggested by oldhermit's answer. It was east of the tabernacle, [east](https://biblestudentsdaily.com/2016/10/28/study-5-the-camp-the-israelites/) of the precinct of Judah.

Numbers 19:3
New International Version

> Give it to Eleazar the priest; it is to be taken **outside the camp** and slaughtered in his presence.

The red heifer was a type of Christ.
It is a shadow pointing to the true type in
Hebrews 13:12

> And so Jesus also suffered **outside the city gate** to make the people holy through his own blood.

Jesus was the sinless antitype who was sacrificed outside the precincts of Jerusalem. According to tradition, the Church of the Holy Sepulchre is the site where Jesus was crucified. It is located in the northeast of today's central Jerusalem.

Answer (score 0):

Verse 4 is very specific that the place of sacrifice was to be made in such a place that it was facing the entrance of the tabernacle. The priest would dip his finger in the blood and sprinkle it seven times in the direction of the front of the tent of meeting. This would suggest that the place of sacrifice would have been east of the camp facing westward toward the front of the tabernacle since the front of the tabernacle always faced east.